# How do I count all DISTINCT ID groups, that exceed a certain number, and then return these IDs?

Tags: mysql

**Introduction:**

I want to set a limit for how many technical tests, a user can take. Once that limit is exceeded, I want to delete the remainder, which will represent the earliest submitted technical tests.
First in, first out type of system.

**Detail:**

```
MySQL 5.5
```

Using the following SQL:

```
/*
Navicat MySQL Data Transfer

Source Server         : local
Source Server Version : 50562
Source Host           : localhost:3306
Source Database       : devtester-blog

Target Server Type    : MYSQL
Target Server Version : 50562
File Encoding         : 65001

Date: 2024-01-08 20:50:01
*/

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for tbluserquestion
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbluserquestion`;
CREATE TABLE `tbluserquestion` (
  `UserQuestion_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `User_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Question_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Technical_test_uuid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Answer_text` longtext,
  `Duration` int(11) DEFAULT '10',
  `Submission_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserQuestion_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1663 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of tbluserquestion
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('23', '1', '36', '6f21885b-fe56-0a35-3dd181707f656b08', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:44:28');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('24', '1', '37', '6f21885b-fe56-0a35-3dd181707f656b08', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:44:28');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('25', '1', '43', '6f21885b-fe56-0a35-3dd181707f656b08', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:44:28');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('26', '1', '41', '6f21885b-fe56-0a35-3dd181707f656b08', 'async', '10', '2023-10-17 16:44:28');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('27', '1', '38', '6f34ce31-987b-cb1e-a676985c54114a46', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('28', '1', '40', '6f34ce31-987b-cb1e-a676985c54114a46', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('29', '1', '41', '6f34ce31-987b-cb1e-a676985c54114a46', 'asyncXXXX', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('30', '1', '42', '6f34ce31-987b-cb1e-a676985c54114a46', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('31', '1', '45', '6f34ce31-987b-cb1e-a676985c54114a46', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('44', '1', '37', 'ff38ad50-e835-447a-49e220375e3f7769', '', '10', '2023-10-25 11:12:37');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('45', '1', '39', 'ff38ad50-e835-447a-49e220375e3f7769', '', '10', '2023-10-25 11:12:37');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('46', '1', '40', 'ff38ad50-e835-447a-49e220375e3f7769', '', '10', '2023-10-25 11:12:37');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('47', '1', '42', 'ff38ad50-e835-447a-49e220375e3f7769', '', '10', '2023-10-25 11:12:37');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('48', '1', '43', 'ff38ad50-e835-447a-49e220375e3f7769', '', '10', '2023-10-25 11:12:37');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('188', '1', '43', 'ac9dad15-f677-8816-50eba2056f77e9ce', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:22:01');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('189', '1', '45', 'ac9dad15-f677-8816-50eba2056f77e9ce', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:22:01');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('190', '1', '47', 'ac9dad15-f677-8816-50eba2056f77e9ce', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:22:01');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('191', '1', '46', 'ac9dad15-f677-8816-50eba2056f77e9ce', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:22:01');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('192', '1', '42', 'ac9dad15-f677-8816-50eba2056f77e9ce', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:22:01');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('193', '1', '43', 'acafb668-aa4a-fa1e-a91ab2a0f6005d7f', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:23:59');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('194', '1', '42', 'acafb668-aa4a-fa1e-a91ab2a0f6005d7f', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:23:59');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('195', '1', '44', 'acafb668-aa4a-fa1e-a91ab2a0f6005d7f', 'nav', '10', '2023-12-22 11:23:59');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('196', '1', '45', 'acafb668-aa4a-fa1e-a91ab2a0f6005d7f', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:23:59');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('197', '1', '46', 'acafb668-aa4a-fa1e-a91ab2a0f6005d7f', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:23:59');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('198', '1', '46', 'acbe4c54-974e-5a75-fd0a74fb06c69171', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:25:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('199', '1', '47', 'acbe4c54-974e-5a75-fd0a74fb06c69171', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:25:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('200', '1', '45', 'acbe4c54-974e-5a75-fd0a74fb06c69171', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:25:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('201', '1', '44', 'acbe4c54-974e-5a75-fd0a74fb06c69171', 'nav', '10', '2023-12-22 11:25:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('202', '1', '42', 'acbe4c54-974e-5a75-fd0a74fb06c69171', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:25:35');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('733', '1', '37', '14c7e6ed-ff42-110b-dc4cbaa2e34f80c5', '', '10', '2023-12-24 11:54:33');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('734', '1', '36', '14c7e6ed-ff42-110b-dc4cbaa2e34f80c5', '', '10', '2023-12-24 11:54:33');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('735', '1', '41', '14c7e6ed-ff42-110b-dc4cbaa2e34f80c5', 'nav', '10', '2023-12-24 11:54:33');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('736', '1', '39', '14c7e6ed-ff42-110b-dc4cbaa2e34f80c5', '', '10', '2023-12-24 11:54:33');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('737', '1', '38', '14c7e6ed-ff42-110b-dc4cbaa2e34f80c5', '', '10', '2023-12-24 11:54:33');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('738', '1', '40', '14d8c247-fa69-7dff-72fc601dadb06df9', '', '10', '2023-12-24 11:56:23');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('739', '1', '38', '14d8c247-fa69-7dff-72fc601dadb06df9', '', '10', '2023-12-24 11:56:23');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('740', '1', '39', '14d8c247-fa69-7dff-72fc601dadb06df9', '', '10', '2023-12-24 11:56:23');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('741', '1', '36', '14d8c247-fa69-7dff-72fc601dadb06df9', '', '10', '2023-12-24 11:56:23');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('742', '1', '41', '14d8c247-fa69-7dff-72fc601dadb06df9', 'async', '10', '2023-12-24 11:56:23');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1198', '1', '40', 'eba21284-9a25-dbbf-748ab2a62aa3e314', '', '10', '2024-01-02 15:20:02');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1199', '1', '37', 'eba21284-9a25-dbbf-748ab2a62aa3e314', '', '10', '2024-01-02 15:20:02');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1200', '1', '38', 'eba21284-9a25-dbbf-748ab2a62aa3e314', '', '10', '2024-01-02 15:20:02');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1201', '1', '39', 'eba21284-9a25-dbbf-748ab2a62aa3e314', '', '10', '2024-01-02 15:20:02');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1202', '1', '41', 'eba21284-9a25-dbbf-748ab2a62aa3e314', 'async', '10', '2024-01-02 15:20:02');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1213', '1', '41', 'effd132a-991e-e99c-236c68dc5f167090', 'async', '10', '2024-01-02 17:21:49');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1214', '1', '39', 'effd132a-991e-e99c-236c68dc5f167090', '', '10', '2024-01-02 17:21:49');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1215', '1', '38', 'effd132a-991e-e99c-236c68dc5f167090', '', '10', '2024-01-02 17:21:49');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1216', '1', '37', 'effd132a-991e-e99c-236c68dc5f167090', '', '10', '2024-01-02 17:21:49');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1217', '1', '36', 'effd132a-991e-e99c-236c68dc5f167090', '', '10', '2024-01-02 17:21:49');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1218', '1', '39', 'f01edf85-c805-dfa1-c0f9d8ece9b2bf20', '', '10', '2024-01-02 17:25:31');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1219', '1', '36', 'f01edf85-c805-dfa1-c0f9d8ece9b2bf20', '', '10', '2024-01-02 17:25:31');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1220', '1', '38', 'f01edf85-c805-dfa1-c0f9d8ece9b2bf20', '', '10', '2024-01-02 17:25:31');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1221', '1', '37', 'f01edf85-c805-dfa1-c0f9d8ece9b2bf20', '', '10', '2024-01-02 17:25:31');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1222', '1', '41', 'f01edf85-c805-dfa1-c0f9d8ece9b2bf20', 'async', '10', '2024-01-02 17:25:31');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1313', '1', '45', 'f535c6d7-c4c9-1006-ef99f2bffb0df9d7', '', '10', '2024-01-02 19:47:49');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1314', '1', '47', 'f535c6d7-c4c9-1006-ef99f2bffb0df9d7', '', '10', '2024-01-02 19:47:49');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1315', '1', '42', 'f535c6d7-c4c9-1006-ef99f2bffb0df9d7', '', '10', '2024-01-02 19:47:49');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1316', '1', '46', 'f535c6d7-c4c9-1006-ef99f2bffb0df9d7', '', '10', '2024-01-02 19:47:49');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1317', '1', '43', 'f535c6d7-c4c9-1006-ef99f2bffb0df9d7', '', '10', '2024-01-02 19:47:49');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1328', '1', '46', 'f57b0d9a-972a-61c3-84f7bc1463a71124', '', '10', '2024-01-02 19:55:23');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1329', '1', '45', 'f57b0d9a-972a-61c3-84f7bc1463a71124', '', '10', '2024-01-02 19:55:23');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1330', '1', '44', 'f57b0d9a-972a-61c3-84f7bc1463a71124', 'nav', '10', '2024-01-02 19:55:23');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1331', '1', '42', 'f57b0d9a-972a-61c3-84f7bc1463a71124', '', '10', '2024-01-02 19:55:23');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('1332', '1', '43', 'f57b0d9a-972a-61c3-84f7bc1463a71124', '', '10', '2024-01-02 19:55:23');
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

**Objective:**

How would I write a SQL query that returns N number of distinct *Technical_test_uuid*, if the amount of distinct *Technical_test_uuids* are greater than 10. So, if there are 13 groups of *Technical_test_uuid*, then 3 distinct *Technical_test_uuid* would be returned. These 3 records would represent the earliest *Technical_test_uuid* by *Submission_date*

There are 13 distinct groups of *Technical_test_uuids*, in this table.

**Query:**

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT Technical_test_uuid
FROM tblUserQuestion uq 
WHERE 
    Technical_test_uuid IN (
        SELECT Technical_test_uuid  
        FROM tblUserQuestion
        WHERE User_ID = uq.User_ID AND Technical_test_uuid IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT(Technical_test_uuid)
            FROM tblUserQuestion
            WHERE User_ID = uq.User_ID
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(Technical_test_uuid)) > 10
        )
    )
GROUP BY uq.Technical_test_uuid
```

But it only returns one result, when it should return 3

```
Technical_test_uuid
6f21885b-fe56-0a35-3dd181707f656b08
```

I would expect the following result:

```
Technical_test_uuid
6f21885b-fe56-0a35-3dd181707f656b08
6f34ce31-987b-cb1e-a676985c54114a46
ff38ad50-e835-447a-49e220375e3f7769
```

Please understand that I want to count all the DISTINCT *Technical_test_uuid*, in the table, and not the amount of *Technical_test_uuid*, in each group?

**UPDATE:**
*09.01.2024*

Thanks very much to both @Barmar and @blabla_bingo for their solutions.
In the end, I went for the @blabla_bingo solution, because it works with MySQL 5.5.
The solution that @Barmar provided is much simpler and works if you have a more modern MySQL engine.
The @blabla_bingo solution managed to work if a user has more DISTINCT Technical_test_uuid than the NLIMIT value, but did not adhere to my requirements, if the user had less DISTINCT Technical_test_uuid than the NLIMIT value.

However, I found a very simple solution that satisfies both requirements:

```
select * 
from (select distinct user_id,technical_test_uuid
     from tbluserquestion t
     where user_id in (select user_id from tbluserquestion group by user_id having count(distinct technical_test_uuid) <= 0)
     group by user_id,technical_test_uuid
     UNION
     select tx.user_id,technical_test_uuid
     from (select user_id,technical_test_uuid,
            if(user_id=@user_id, @row_id:=@row_id+1,@row_id:=1) as row_id,if(user_id=@user_id,@user_id,@user_id:=user_id) as u_id 
            from (select user_id,technical_test_uuid
                  from tbluserquestion tb
                  where user_id in (select user_id from tbluserquestion group by user_id having count(distinct technical_test_uuid) > 5)
                  group by user_id,technical_test_uuid
                  order by user_id,min(submission_date)
                  ) t1, (select @user_id:=0,@row_id:=1) t2
            ) tx
     join (select t1.i*10+t0.i+1 as u_id
            from (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
                 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1
           order by u_id
          ) return_id
     on tx.row_id=return_id.u_id
     join (select user_id,count(distinct technical_test_uuid) dist_row_count from tbluserquestion group by user_id) tbl_row_count
     on tx.user_id=tbl_row_count.user_id and tx.row_id<=tbl_row_count.dist_row_count - 5
) tbl
order by user_id
```

All I did was add zero to the first NLIMIT value:

```
where user_id in (select user_id from tbluserquestion group by user_id having count(distinct technical_test_uuid) <= 0)
```

I have now **accepted** the @blabla_bingo solution :)

Comment: What do you mean by "Please understand that I want to count all the DISTINCT Technical_test_uuid, in the table, and not the amount of Technical_test_uuid, in each group?". In a comment below you said you want 10 per user.

Comment: The two comments are not related. The comment above is more of a caveat. Certain solutions that ChatGPT gave me, tried to test the limit against the number of Technical_test_uuid in each group, rather than the number of DISTINCT Technical_test_uuid in the table

Comment: Rewrite to use `JOIN` instead of `IN ( SELECT ... )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a UNION to differentiate the two cases (users whose number of distinct question_uuid>10, and users whose number of distinct question_uuid<=10 ) . But first of all,let's add 3 more user_id at the end of the original INSERT statements:

```
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10023', '2', '36', 'user_2_01', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:44:28');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10024', '2', '37', 'user_2_01', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:44:28');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10025', '2', '43', 'user_2_02', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:44:28');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10026', '2', '41', 'user_2_02', 'async', '10', '2023-10-17 16:44:28');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10027', '2', '38', 'user_2_03', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10028', '2', '40', 'user_2_03', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10029', '2', '41', 'user_2_03', 'asyncXXXX', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10030', '3', '42', 'user_3_01', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10031', '3', '45', 'user_3_01', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10044', '3', '37', 'user_3_02', '', '10', '2023-10-25 11:12:37');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10045', '3', '39', 'user_3_03', '', '10', '2023-10-25 11:12:37');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10046', '3', '40', 'user_3_04', '', '10', '2023-10-25 11:12:37');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10047', '3', '42', 'user_3_05', '', '10', '2023-10-25 11:12:37');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10048', '3', '43', 'user_3_06', '', '10', '2023-10-25 11:12:37');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('100188', '3', '43', 'user_3_07', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:22:01');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('100189', '3', '45', 'user_3_08', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:22:01');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('100190', '3', '47', 'user_3_09', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:22:01');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('100191', '3', '46', 'user_3_10', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:22:01');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('100192', '3', '42', 'user_3_11', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:22:01');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('100193', '3', '43', 'user_3_12', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:23:59');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('100194', '4', '42', 'user_4_01', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:23:59');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('100195', '4', '44', 'user_4_01', 'nav', '10', '2023-12-22 11:23:59');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('100196', '4', '45', 'user_4_02', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:23:59');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('100197', '4', '46', 'user_4_02', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:23:59');

select distinct user_id,technical_test_uuid from tbluserquestion ;
-- result (with user_id 1 and 3 have over 10 distinct test_uuid):
+---------+-------------------------------------+
| user_id | technical_test_uuid                 |
+---------+-------------------------------------+
|       1 | 6f21885b-fe56-0a35-3dd181707f656b08 |
|       1 | 6f34ce31-987b-cb1e-a676985c54114a46 |
|       1 | ff38ad50-e835-447a-49e220375e3f7769 |
|       1 | ac9dad15-f677-8816-50eba2056f77e9ce |
|       1 | acafb668-aa4a-fa1e-a91ab2a0f6005d7f |
|       1 | acbe4c54-974e-5a75-fd0a74fb06c69171 |
|       1 | 14c7e6ed-ff42-110b-dc4cbaa2e34f80c5 |
|       1 | 14d8c247-fa69-7dff-72fc601dadb06df9 |
|       1 | eba21284-9a25-dbbf-748ab2a62aa3e314 |
|       1 | effd132a-991e-e99c-236c68dc5f167090 |
|       1 | f01edf85-c805-dfa1-c0f9d8ece9b2bf20 |
|       1 | f535c6d7-c4c9-1006-ef99f2bffb0df9d7 |
|       1 | f57b0d9a-972a-61c3-84f7bc1463a71124 |
|       2 | user_2_01                           |
|       2 | user_2_02                           |
|       2 | user_2_03                           |
|       3 | user_3_01                           |
|       3 | user_3_02                           |
|       3 | user_3_03                           |
|       3 | user_3_04                           |
|       3 | user_3_05                           |
|       3 | user_3_06                           |
|       3 | user_3_07                           |
|       3 | user_3_08                           |
|       3 | user_3_09                           |
|       3 | user_3_10                           |
|       3 | user_3_11                           |
|       3 | user_3_12                           |
|       4 | user_4_01                           |
|       4 | user_4_02                           |
+---------+-------------------------------------+
```

Here is the query to do it.  As MySQL 5.5 DOES NOT support window functions, we need to go a long way by using user variables to generate row numbers. It's a tricky one.

```
select * 
from (select distinct user_id,technical_test_uuid
     from tbluserquestion t
     where user_id in (select user_id from tbluserquestion group by user_id having count(distinct technical_test_uuid) <=10)
     group by user_id,technical_test_uuid
     UNION
     select user_id,technical_test_uuid
     from (select user_id,technical_test_uuid,
            if(user_id=@user_id, @row_id:=@row_id+1,@row_id:=1) as row_id,if(user_id=@user_id,@user_id,@user_id:=user_id) as u_id 
            from (select user_id,technical_test_uuid
                  from tbluserquestion
                  where user_id in (select user_id from tbluserquestion group by user_id having count(distinct technical_test_uuid) >10)
                  group by user_id,technical_test_uuid
                  order by user_id,min(submission_date)) t1, (select @user_id:=0,@row_id:=1) t2
            ) tx
     join (select 1 u_id union select 2 union select 3) limit_3
     on tx.row_id=limit_3.u_id
) tbl
order by user_id
;

-- result set:
+---------+-------------------------------------+
| user_id | technical_test_uuid                 |
+---------+-------------------------------------+
|       1 | 6f21885b-fe56-0a35-3dd181707f656b08 |
|       1 | 6f34ce31-987b-cb1e-a676985c54114a46 |
|       1 | ff38ad50-e835-447a-49e220375e3f7769 |
|       2 | user_2_01                           |
|       2 | user_2_02                           |
|       2 | user_2_03                           |
|       3 | user_3_01                           |
|       3 | user_3_02                           |
|       3 | user_3_03                           |
|       4 | user_4_01                           |
|       4 | user_4_02                           |
+---------+-------------------------------------+
```

See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6S8RTqevYA4UHD8tba24mU/0

**UPDATED SECTION** 
Based on the OP's comments , the number of returned distinct uuid for a user is determined by (the number of distinct uuid of the user **minus**  the limit_number) starting from the earliest submission date. 
Since we know the limit_number varies(so is the return number), the previous `(select 1 u_id union select 2 union select 3) limit_3` is no longer eligible. We will need a return_id table which should cover the highest possible number of distinct uuid for a user.

```
-- supposing the highest can be no more than 100
select t1.i*10+t0.i+1 as u_id
from (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1
order by u_id     
;
-- result 
+------+
| u_id |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
|    6 |
|    7 |
|    8 |
|    9 |
|   10 |
|   11 |
|   12 |

-- all the way to 100

|   95 |
|   96 |
|   97 |
|   98 |
|   99 |
|  100 |
+------+
```

Now let's rebuild the table.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for tbluserquestion
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbluserquestion`;
CREATE TABLE `tbluserquestion` (
  `UserQuestion_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `User_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Question_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Technical_test_uuid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Answer_text` longtext,
  `Duration` int(11) DEFAULT '10',
  `Submission_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserQuestion_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1663 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of tbluserquestion
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('23', '1', '36', '6f21885b-fe56-0a35-3dd181707f656b08', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:44:28');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('24', '1', '37', '6f21885b-fe56-0a35-3dd181707f656b08', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:44:28');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('25', '1', '43', '6f21885b-fe56-0a35-3dd181707f656b08', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:44:28');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('26', '1', '41', '6f21885b-fe56-0a35-3dd181707f656b08', 'async', '10', '2023-10-17 16:44:28');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('27', '1', '38', '6f34ce31-987b-cb1e-a676985c54114a46', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('28', '1', '40', '6f34ce31-987b-cb1e-a676985c54114a46', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('29', '1', '41', '6f34ce31-987b-cb1e-a676985c54114a46', 'asyncXXXX', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('30', '1', '42', '6f34ce31-987b-cb1e-a676985c54114a46', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('31', '1', '45', '6f34ce31-987b-cb1e-a676985c54114a46', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('44', '1', '37', 'ff38ad50-e835-447a-49e220375e3f7769', '', '10', '2023-10-25 11:12:37');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('45', '1', '39', 'ff38ad50-e835-447a-49e220375e3f7769', '', '10', '2023-10-25 11:12:37');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('46', '1', '40', 'ff38ad50-e835-447a-49e220375e3f7769', '', '10', '2023-10-25 11:12:37');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('47', '1', '42', 'ff38ad50-e835-447a-49e220375e3f7769', '', '10', '2023-10-25 11:12:37');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('48', '1', '43', 'ff38ad50-e835-447a-49e220375e3f7769', '', '10', '2023-10-25 11:12:37');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('188', '1', '43', 'ac9dad15-f677-8816-50eba2056f77e9ce', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:22:01');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('189', '1', '45', 'ac9dad15-f677-8816-50eba2056f77e9ce', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:22:01');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('190', '1', '47', 'ac9dad15-f677-8816-50eba2056f77e9ce', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:22:01');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('191', '1', '46', 'ac9dad15-f677-8816-50eba2056f77e9ce', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:22:01');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('192', '1', '42', 'ac9dad15-f677-8816-50eba2056f77e9ce', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:22:01');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('193', '1', '43', 'acafb668-aa4a-fa1e-a91ab2a0f6005d7f', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:23:59');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('194', '1', '42', 'acafb668-aa4a-fa1e-a91ab2a0f6005d7f', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:23:59');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('195', '1', '44', 'acafb668-aa4a-fa1e-a91ab2a0f6005d7f', 'nav', '10', '2023-12-22 11:23:59');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('196', '1', '45', 'acafb668-aa4a-fa1e-a91ab2a0f6005d7f', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:23:59');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('197', '1', '46', 'acafb668-aa4a-fa1e-a91ab2a0f6005d7f', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:23:59');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('198', '1', '46', 'acbe4c54-974e-5a75-fd0a74fb06c69171', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:25:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('199', '1', '47', 'acbe4c54-974e-5a75-fd0a74fb06c69171', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:25:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('200', '1', '45', 'acbe4c54-974e-5a75-fd0a74fb06c69171', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:25:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('201', '1', '44', 'acbe4c54-974e-5a75-fd0a74fb06c69171', 'nav', '10', '2023-12-22 11:25:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('202', '1', '42', 'acbe4c54-974e-5a75-fd0a74fb06c69171', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:25:35');

INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10023', '2', '36', 'user_2_01', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:44:28');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10024', '2', '37', 'user_2_01', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:44:28');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10025', '2', '43', 'user_2_02', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:44:28');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10026', '2', '41', 'user_2_03', 'async', '10', '2023-10-17 16:44:28');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10027', '2', '38', 'user_2_04', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10028', '2', '40', 'user_2_05', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10029', '2', '41', 'user_2_06', 'asyncXXXX', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10030', '2', '41', 'user_2_07', 'asyncXXXX', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10031', '2', '41', 'user_2_07', 'asyncXXXX', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');

INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10032', '3', '42', 'user_3_01', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10033', '3', '45', 'user_3_01', '', '10', '2023-10-17 16:46:34');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10044', '3', '37', 'user_3_02', '', '10', '2023-10-25 11:12:37');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10045', '3', '39', 'user_3_03', '', '10', '2023-10-25 11:12:37');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10046', '3', '40', 'user_3_04', '', '10', '2023-10-25 11:12:37');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10047', '3', '42', 'user_3_05', '', '10', '2023-10-25 11:12:37');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('10048', '3', '43', 'user_3_06', '', '10', '2023-10-25 11:12:37');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('100188', '3', '43', 'user_3_07', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:22:01');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('100189', '3', '45', 'user_3_08', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:22:01');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('100190', '3', '47', 'user_3_09', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:22:01');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('100191', '3', '46', 'user_3_10', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:22:01');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('100192', '3', '42', 'user_3_11', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:22:01');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('100193', '3', '43', 'user_3_12', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:23:59');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('100194', '4', '42', 'user_4_01', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:23:59');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('100195', '4', '44', 'user_4_01', 'nav', '10', '2023-12-22 11:23:59');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('100196', '4', '45', 'user_4_02', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:23:59');
INSERT INTO `tbluserquestion` VALUES ('100197', '4', '46', 'user_4_02', '', '10', '2023-12-22 11:23:59');

select distinct user_id,technical_test_uuid from tbluserquestion ;
+---------+-------------------------------------+
| user_id | technical_test_uuid                 |
+---------+-------------------------------------+
|       1 | 6f21885b-fe56-0a35-3dd181707f656b08 |
|       1 | 6f34ce31-987b-cb1e-a676985c54114a46 |
|       1 | ff38ad50-e835-447a-49e220375e3f7769 |
|       1 | ac9dad15-f677-8816-50eba2056f77e9ce |
|       1 | acafb668-aa4a-fa1e-a91ab2a0f6005d7f |
|       1 | acbe4c54-974e-5a75-fd0a74fb06c69171 |
|       2 | user_2_01                           |
|       2 | user_2_02                           |
|       2 | user_2_03                           |
|       2 | user_2_04                           |
|       2 | user_2_05                           |
|       2 | user_2_06                           |
|       2 | user_2_07                           |
|       3 | user_3_01                           |
|       3 | user_3_02                           |
|       3 | user_3_03                           |
|       3 | user_3_04                           |
|       3 | user_3_05                           |
|       3 | user_3_06                           |
|       3 | user_3_07                           |
|       3 | user_3_08                           |
|       3 | user_3_09                           |
|       3 | user_3_10                           |
|       3 | user_3_11                           |
|       3 | user_3_12                           |
|       4 | user_4_01                           |
|       4 | user_4_02                           |
+---------+-------------------------------------+
```

As displayed above, this time user1 has 6 distinct uuid while user2 has 7,user3 has 12 and user4 has 2. And the limit is set to 5 as OP suggested. Now let's get the job done once and for all.

```
select * 
from (select distinct user_id,technical_test_uuid
     from tbluserquestion t
     where user_id in (select user_id from tbluserquestion group by user_id having count(distinct technical_test_uuid) <=5)
     group by user_id,technical_test_uuid
     UNION
     select tx.user_id,technical_test_uuid
     from (select user_id,technical_test_uuid,
            if(user_id=@user_id, @row_id:=@row_id+1,@row_id:=1) as row_id,if(user_id=@user_id,@user_id,@user_id:=user_id) as u_id 
            from (select user_id,technical_test_uuid
                  from tbluserquestion tb
                  where user_id in (select user_id from tbluserquestion group by user_id having count(distinct technical_test_uuid) >5)
                  group by user_id,technical_test_uuid
                  order by user_id,min(submission_date)
                  ) t1, (select @user_id:=0,@row_id:=1) t2
            ) tx
     join (select t1.i*10+t0.i+1 as u_id
            from (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
                 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1
           order by u_id
          ) return_id
     on tx.row_id=return_id.u_id
     join (select user_id,count(distinct technical_test_uuid) dist_row_count from tbluserquestion group by user_id) tbl_row_count
     on tx.user_id=tbl_row_count.user_id and tx.row_id<=tbl_row_count.dist_row_count - 5
) tbl
order by user_id
;
-- result:
+---------+-------------------------------------+
| user_id | technical_test_uuid                 |
+---------+-------------------------------------+
|       1 | 6f21885b-fe56-0a35-3dd181707f656b08 |
|       2 | user_2_01                           |
|       2 | user_2_02                           |
|       3 | user_3_01                           |
|       3 | user_3_02                           |
|       3 | user_3_03                           |
|       3 | user_3_04                           |
|       3 | user_3_05                           |
|       3 | user_3_06                           |
|       3 | user_3_07                           |
|       4 | user_4_01                           |
|       4 | user_4_02                           |
+---------+-------------------------------------+
```

Also tested it on https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/skyWhkYozUfYP4dMJ8CW3W/0

**FINAL UPDATE** 
If you have no need to query for those who have less distinct uuid than the Nlimit, just remove the first UNION part as well as the outmost SELECT statement.

```
     select tx.user_id,technical_test_uuid
     from (select user_id,technical_test_uuid,
            if(user_id=@user_id, @row_id:=@row_id+1,@row_id:=1) as row_id,if(user_id=@user_id,@user_id,@user_id:=user_id) as u_id 
            from (select user_id,technical_test_uuid
                  from tbluserquestion tb
                  where user_id in (select user_id from tbluserquestion group by user_id having count(distinct technical_test_uuid) >5)
                  group by user_id,technical_test_uuid
                  order by user_id,min(submission_date)
                  ) t1, (select @user_id:=0,@row_id:=1) t2
            ) tx
     join (select t1.i*10+t0.i+1 as u_id
            from (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
                 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1
           order by u_id
          ) return_id
     on tx.row_id=return_id.u_id
     join (select user_id,count(distinct technical_test_uuid) dist_row_count from tbluserquestion group by user_id) tbl_row_count
     on tx.user_id=tbl_row_count.user_id and tx.row_id<=tbl_row_count.dist_row_count - 5
     order by user_id
;

-- result
+---------+-------------------------------------+
| user_id | technical_test_uuid                 |
+---------+-------------------------------------+
|       1 | 6f21885b-fe56-0a35-3dd181707f656b08 |
|       2 | user_2_01                           |
|       2 | user_2_02                           |
|       3 | user_3_01                           |
|       3 | user_3_02                           |
|       3 | user_3_03                           |
|       3 | user_3_04                           |
|       3 | user_3_05                           |
|       3 | user_3_06                           |
|       3 | user_3_07                           |
+---------+-------------------------------------+
```

As the first UNION part is omitted, outcome for user4 who has only 2 distinct uuid is no longer displayed.

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks you so much., I have done a preliminary test on this and it works beautifully. I will do some multi user tests, later this morning and, if everything goes well, I will accept your answer.

Comment: OK. I have done some further testing. I added User_ID of 2 to the last 7 tests and reduced the LIMIT from 10 to 5. Now, User_ID = 1 has 6 unique technical tests and User_ID = 2 has 7 unique technical tests. I would expect to get 1 result for User_ID = 1 and 2 results for User_ID = 2, but I get 3 results for each?

Comment: @Charles Robertson Could you clarify `returns N number of distinct Technical_test_uuid, if the amount of distinct Technical_test_uuids are greater than 10.` Does this mean the number of returned uuid for each user is not fixed depending on the limit ? e.g If the limit is 10 and there are 13 distinct Technical_test_uuid for a user, then the 3 earliest distinct Technical_test_uuid would be returned. And If the limit is still 10 and there are 21 distinct Technical_test_uuid for a user, then the 11 earliest distinct Technical_test_uuid would be returned?

Comment: Yes. The number of records returned per user is not fixed. 
Based on a LIMIT of 10. 
So, if User_ID = 1 has 15 DISTINCT Technical_test_uuid, he will get back 5 DISTINCT Technical_test_uuid. If User_ID = 2 has 12 DISTINCT Technical_test_uuid, he will get back 2 DISTINCT Technical_test_uuid. If User_ID = 3 has 25 DISTINCT Technical_test_uuid, he will get back 15 DISTINCT Technical_test_uuid.

Comment: Let me explain the point behind this query. Once the Technical_test_uuid are returned, I will use them to delete records, so that every user has the same amount technical tests in the DB. Every night, I will be running a scheduled task that will run this query and delete records. 
Hopefully, users won’t have too many Technical_test_uuid over the limit, because it will only be 24 hours worth of testing time, each time this query runs.

Comment: @Charles Robertson Check the updated section.

Comment: There is one issue I have found. If I set the NLIMIT value to something greater than the amount of DISTINCT Technical_test_uuid per user, I get records returned. No records should be returned for a user, that has less DISTINCT Technical_test_uuid than the NLIMIT value
But everything works, if the user has more DISTINCT Technical_test_uuid than the NLIMIT value.
So, your update is half correct and a great improvement. Thank you.

Comment: To be honest I don't understand what that first UNION is all about? It is looking for a COUNT that is less than or equal to the NLIMIT value? I don't really want any records returned that are less than the NLIMIT

Comment: OK. I have found an easy solution to save you from having to do anymore work. I have just set the first UNION NLIMIT value to 0, and now everything works perfectly! Thank you so much for all your hard work. **I will accept this answer as the solution** :)

Comment: @Charles Robertson The first UNION is to get all available distinct uuid for users who have less distinct uuid than the Nlimit. If you don't need that,just remove it including the UNION keyword. Setting the Nlimit to 0 in the first UNION does work around the issue but not without impacting the performance. Nevertheless, in the future, if you do need to get both outcome at one go, you can add the first UNION again.

Comment: Querying for different results based on mutually exclusive search conditions (e.g distinct uuid<=nlimit , distinct uuid>nlimit) at the same time is one of the reasons we use UNION.

Comment: Please check the final update.

Answer (score 1):

See [Restrict results to top N rows per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/restrict-results-to-top-n-rows-per-group) for how to get the top N per group. First get the earliest submission grouped by user ID and test UID. From that, get all *except* the latest 10 grouped by user ID.

```
WITH earliest_by_user_test AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User_ID, Technical_test_uuid) AS rn
  FROM tbluserquestion
), group_by_user AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User_ID ORDER BY Submission_date DESC) AS rn1
  FROM earliest_by_user_test
  WHERE rn = 1
)

SELECT User_ID, technical_test_uuid
FROM group_by_user
WHERE rn1 > 10
ORDER BY Submission_date;
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cSMCGr8UwoakpT4E2FRj1q/1)

Comment: I am afraid your solution returns zero records? I replaced my innermost query for yours and it returned no records at all?

Comment: I'm not really sure about the rest of the query logic, either. Could you post some sample data and the desired result? Do you want 10 questions per user?

Comment: Yes. I want to limit each user to 10 technical tests which equates to 10 x DISTINCT Technical_test_uuid. As far as data is concerned, you can recreate the table by running the SQL, I have provided in a Query builder. I use Navicat for MySQL

Comment: Then you want something involving `GROUP BY User_ID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Technical_test_uuid) > 10`

Comment: I didn't scroll down, I didn't realize you posted the `INSERT` lines.

Comment: Yes. And you can the online SQL tool at https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler And I think the WHERE User_ID = uq.User_ID provides the referential integrity that is required to limit each subquery to a user from the parent query

Comment: Correlated subqueries can only reference one level out, I don't think the 2nd-level subquery can refer to `uq`.

Comment: I generally recommend using JOIN instead of correlated subqueries.

Comment: I have to go out now, sorry I can't finish correcting my answer.

Comment: I've updated the answer and tested the code. It returns the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for your effort here, but I get an error, when testing your answer: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'earliest_by_user_test AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User_ID,' at line 44

Comment: It maybe that the version of MySQL that I am using does not accept some of your syntax? I am using MySQL 5.5

Comment: I have now tested your answer in the DB fiddle demo, you kindly provided. I have added multiple users and it works perfectly. I really wish I could see it working in my Navicat Query Builder for MySQL 5.5. It is definitely a correct answer, but I am not sure how to adapt it, to work in MySQL 5.5

Comment: It seems like PARTITION BY became available in MySQL 8. This is why @blabla_bingo is not using a Window function, in his solution. Unfortunately, my client won’t let me update MySQL server, so we are stuck with MySQL 5.5 ☹️

Comment: See the other answers to the linked question, they show how to implement similar things before window functions.